# Meaning of the colon with ampersand in Haskell (:&)

Tags: haskell

Implementation of Stream from [Haskell book (author Anton Kholomiov)](https://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/files/ru-haskell-book.pdf) (page 70)

```
data Stream a = a :& Stream a
```

I understand what meant to do `:&`, but can't find it`s defenition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That *is* the definition. The `Stream` type defines a single infix data constructor called `:&`. Compare to

```
data Stream a = StreamCons a (Stream a)
```

which would define the same type, but creates `StreamCons` instead of `:&` as the data constructor.

Infix data constructors, unlike regular infix operators, *must* begin with a colon.

---

With the `StreamCons` constructor, your `constStream` function would look like

```
constStream :: a -> Stream a
-- constStream x = x :& (constStream x)
constStream x = StreamCons x (constStream x)
```

The same function to return an infinite *list* would look like

```
constList :: a -> [a]
constList x = x : (constList x)
```

`:&` serves the same purpose as `:`, but for a `Stream a` instead of a `[a]`. In fact, the only difference between `Stream` and `[]` is that `Stream a` only contains values representing *infinite* sequences of `a`s, while `[a]` also contains finite lists.